# Counting numbers in a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Is there anyone who can help me to write a function in common LISP that counts the numbers in a list?
The code that I have written is below, but it does not work!

```
(defun count-numbers(lst)
    (let(result()))
    (dolist(number lst)
    (push number result))
    (length result))
```

For example, when I enter this query `"(count'(r 4 f d w 2 3 4 1 z))"`, I must get 5.

Comment: I've been striving to solve it. But since I'm new to this programming language, I can't get it done!

Comment: when i think back to the functional programming class that I took, I would have probably done something like this using recursion.

Answer (score 5):

Since it's homework, I'll just give some pointers. First: simplicity. If you are new to Common-Lisp, just use its basic features. For example: **recursion**. In pure functional style. Think about something like this:

```
(defun count (list counter) 
    ;; something
)
```

we first check *list*. If it's empty, we already checked all the elements, so we return *counter*. If *list* is not empty, we

1. take its first element
2. we check if it's a number
3. it's a number! We recursively call **count** on the rest of the list and with counter = counter + 1
4. it's not a number! We recursively call **count** on the rest of the list with *counter* the same as before

Use (numberp n). It returns T if *n* is a number, NIL if not.

Comment: At first I didn't noticed the homework tag. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help.
But just one question. What is the purpose of the "#" sign before "numberp"?
And "numberp" checks whether it is a number or not, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm now trying to write the function myself since there will be no marks in case of using built-in functions. But anyway, thanks.

Comment: In order to take the first element I should pop the value.
(defun count (lst counter)
(pop lst)
)
Then how can I store the value of the popped object? Is (pop lst x) right??

Comment: You don't need to "pop" the value. Just use (car list). It returns the first element of the list.

Comment: (defun count (lst counter)
              (let (counter 0))
              (if(numberp car lst)) (+ counter 1)
              )
Does this check whether it is a number or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun count-numbers (lst)
  (let (result ()))
  (dolist (number lst)
     (push number result))
  (length result))
```

Check the indentation. Is that what you wanted? Maybe not.

Then you also push all elements to the result list? Is that what you want?

Here is a list of functions on numbers. http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_number.htm
Maybe there is one you need?

This is a good introductory Lisp book for download:  http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Comment: No actually when I run it I get error!
I think the algorithm is write.

Comment: Do you know what's the way to evaluate whether an atom is a number or a character?

Comment: It looks like the LET is malformed here, shouldn't it be `(let ((result '()))` ... ?

Comment: @postfuturist: right, that's one error. The code is from the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there are a variety of ways to solve this, one would be an imperative loop, like the mostly correct solution already written, a recursive counting function (which is probably the worst way since there's no guarantee in CL that you won't blow the stack), or the functional approach you would probably actually use in production. The last one would be this:

```
(defun count-numbers (list) (count-if #'numberp list))
```